# Any Carousels like this only with thumbnails at the bottom as well?

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

IIm lookin a carousel with the main image in the middle and 2 images to both the right and left hand side  like the following link http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-feature-carousel

However in addition to this i would like there to be thumbnails.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Flexslider, jCarouselLite, cycle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Flexslider is capable of doing what you're looking for: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

Comment: here is a view of what I have... http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d51d92n7e... can i do that with flexislider? and have thumbnails as well? Any Examples?